# Disabling Windows 7 Firewall when Behind a Hardware Router

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall

Is it safe to disable Windows firewall when I'm behind a router? I'm having a few Origin connection problems that I'm hoping can be resolved by disabling Windows firewall. I'm assuming that the router's firewall will do the job just nicely and that any software firewall may just conflict with it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not safe to completely disable the only firewall between you and the internet. Unless you have a hardware firewall, which usually retails in the thousands, you are opening yourself up to serious vulnerabilities. Even then you would still need to configure it to allow your program through.

I would suggest researching which ports your software uses and then opening those ports in Windows Firewall. According to [this article](https://help.ea.com/article/connection-issues-with-origin), the ports you need to open are the following:

- **TCP**: 80; 443; 9960-9969; 1024-1124; 18000; 18120; 18060; 27900; 28910; 29900
- **UDP**: 1024-1124; 18000; 29900

You can learn how to open a port in Windows Firewall by reading [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall) from Microsoft.